# Does orca + RICHPse work on Solaris Containers or local zones?

Tags: solaris, performance, monitoring, solaris-zones

I have just attempted to get RICHPse version 3.4 running on a Solaris version 10 Sun M5000.

It seems to run on the global zone but not on the local zones.

On the local zones RICHPse just fails without issuing any errors.

I have run orca + RICHPse without root access and it seems to run fine on other servers without root. I just set the appropriate environment paths in start_orcallator and it works. I know RICHPse should also normally be placed in /opt (from pkgadd setup) but it seems to work even when located elsewhere (e.g. somewhere in /home and working with non-root ID)--i.e. just running from a copied RICHPse folder. So, I am thinking that is not the issue but something else with the Solaris local zone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commenting or removing the line:

```
#define USE_RAWDISK          1
```

in lib/orcallator.se seems to have fixed the problem for me.